# Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am new to JavaScript, am I was trying to dissect an embedded message. Here's my code, it runs fine for a few mins, works accordingly but idk what goes wrong.

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
    if (message.embeds[i].title.includes("text!")) {
      message.channel.send('reply')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Try to print the message element in the log to see if there’s some empty element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code can fix this problem.

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
    if (message.embeds[i] && message.embeds[i].title.includes("text!")) {
      message.channel.send('reply')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: `bot.on('message', (message) => { 
for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) { if (message.embeds[i] && message.embeds[i].description.includes("✨")) { 
console.log('emoji detected'); 
break; 
} }` 

I did this, and same error showed.

Comment: This won't work if the title property is missing or null.

Answer (score 4):

Its because there is at least one item inside the embeds array items that missing the `title` property.

You will need to update the if statement to be:

```
If (message.embeds[i] &&
 message.embeds[i].title && ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

It means inside `message.embeds[i]` there is at least one element without title property.

You should check first if `message.embeds[i].title` exists and perform other operations after the check.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code more defensive like this. Instead of

```
if(message.embeds[i].title.includes("text!"))
```

you can write the following

```
if(typeof message.embeds[i].title === "string" &&
message.embeds[i].title.includes("text!"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably some of the `embed` object is coming without the `title` property.

You can safely use your logic changing your if condition to:

```
if ('title' in message.embeds[i] && message.embeds[i].title.includes("text!")) {
   /* ... */
}
```

Comment: `bot.on('message', (message) => {

    for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
        if (message.embeds[i] && message.embeds[i].description.includes("✨")) {
             
              console.log('emoji detected');
              break;
              
            }
   }`


I did this, and same error showed.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not a type safe language, and the error is caused by not being type safe. We will have to check if object exists and nested properties exists and after we should be able check the value. In your case:

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {

  // check if main obj and main property exist
  if (message && message.embeds) {

    for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
      // now, check if title exists and after check the text inside
      if (
        message.embeds[i].title && 
        message.embeds[i].title.includes("text!")) 
      {
        message.channel.send('reply')
      }
    }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its null pointer error. some of your object parameter is null but its mapped in html. Please try to add more null checks to avoid this .

always check an item before accessing it

```
bot.on('message', (message) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
    if (message.embeds[i].title && message.embeds[i].title.includes("text!")) {
      message.channel.send('reply')
    }
  }
})
```